# Include xsd schema file into .net core web app

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, xsd

I have a web app, where I want to validate an xml-file. For this validation, I have an xsd file. In this xml I have to validate a signature. For the signature validation, I have to include the

```
xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
```

from the w3c.

In my xsd I have the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Root">...
```

I tested my validation before in a simple console app. The validation works fine there when I add the "xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"-file, I downloaded before from w3c, to the project.

Now I want to do the same in my webapp. So I added the xmldsig-core-schema.xsd to the place of my xsd. I added the file to the solution as content.
But in the webapp it doesn't work.

Does any one have an idea where or how I have to add this file, to get my validation running?

Comment: Please post your answer in the answer section below and remove the `[SOLVED]` part in your question. Have a look here: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have to add the signature schema to my SchemaSet. Then it works.

```
var xsdPath = new FileInfo("my.xsd"));
schemas.Add("", xsdPath.FullName);
xsdPath = new FileInfo("xmldsig-core-schema.xsd");
schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", xsdPath.FullName);
```